# A new environment based on enumerate

Tags: lists, environments, enumitem, optional-arguments

I have defined the following simple environment:

```
\newenvironment{renumerate}{\begin{enumerate}\raggedright}{\end{enumerate}}
```

I wonder how the above can be modified to use with, say, the following:

```
\begin{renumerate}[label=\color{blue}10.\theenumi]
\item blah
\item blah
\end{renumerate}
```

The options given in `[]` are not known in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since you're already loading the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package, it makes sense to use the in-built command `newlist` that it provides for exactly this purpose

```
\newlist{renumerate}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[renumerate]{label=\arabic*,before=\raggedright}
```

This sets up the `renumerate` environment to be based on the standard `enumerate` environment. The `{3}` at the end specifies the maximum depth- you can change this as you see fit.

The `setlist` command is important as it provides the default behaviour of the list. The environment, by default(!), can take optional arguments, thanks to the wizardry of the `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{renumerate}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[renumerate]{label=\arabic*,before=\raggedright}

\begin{document}

\begin{renumerate}[label=10.\arabic*,font=\color{blue}]
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item \lipsum[1]
\end{renumerate}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{renumerate}
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item \lipsum[1]
\end{renumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works as said on the tin.

Answer (score 15):

Add an "empty" optional argument to the environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,xcolor}
\newenvironment{renumerate}[1][,]{\begin{enumerate}[#1]\raggedright}{\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{renumerate}[label=\color{blue}10.\theenumi]
  \item blah
  \item blah
\end{renumerate}
\begin{renumerate}
  \item blah
  \item blah
\end{renumerate}
\end{document}
```

The "empty" optional argument is given as `,`. As reference for the use of mandatory/optional arguments with environments, either see [`source2e`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (`texdoc source2e`) or [LaTeX help with `\newenvironment`](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_20.html).

Perhaps more in line with [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) style, you could use

```
\begin{renumerate}[label=10.\arabic*,font=\color{blue}]
  \item blah
  \item blah
\end{renumerate}
```

Comment: +1 it seems a little more inline with `enumitem` to use `[label=10.\arabic*,font=\color{blue}]`. Same result of course

Comment: [resume] is not working as shown here: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,xcolor}
\newenvironment{renumerate}[1][,]{\begin{enumerate}[#1]\raggedright}{\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{renumerate}[label=\color{blue}10.\theenumi]
  \item blah
  \item blah
\end{renumerate}

\begin{renumerate}
  \item blah
  \item blah
\end{renumerate}

\begin{renumerate}[resume] <--
  \item blah
  \item blah
\end{renumerate}


\end{document}

Comment: @Reza: I'll look into this later. It may be that definitions that `resume` rely on are localized due to the nature of `\newenvironment`. Setting up a list using `\newlist` (as in [cmhughes' answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94760/5764)) circumvents this, and might be the more appropriate alternative.

Comment: Thanks Werner for your reply.  I had a look at cmhughes'answer.  It is fine with [resume] however I cannot get it working with other options say \raggedright, i.e. I want \begin{renumerate}....\end{\enumerate} to always ragged right the items without me having to add \raggedright manually.

Comment: @Reza see my updated answer which includes `raggedright`